# Sql query to calculate total based on 2 conditions in 1 query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below :

```
Employee : 

EmpNo
FirstName
LastName

Dept : 

DeptName
Head
NoOfEmployees

EmpContracts : 

EmpNo  DeptName   Salary    StartDate     EndDate
1      d1         1000      2017-12-12    2018-12-12
1      d2         1000      2017-06-12    2018-12-12
2      d3         1000      2017-06-12    2018-12-12
2      d4         1000      2017-12-12    2018-12-12     
3      d5         4000      2017-12-12    2018-12-12
```

This is what I am trying to do :

> > Display the dept details and the total salary amount for the contracts
> >     on each department, with the following conditions: 1) Calculated total
> >     for contracts must be from employees that work exclusively for that
> >     department 2) Total calculated for the contracts should be after 2001 order result by NoOfEmployees

I am confused with how to satisfy both condition in 1 query ?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
select [EmpNO],[DeptName],[StartDate], SUM([Salary]) from [dbo].[EmpContracts]
group by [EmpNo],[DeptName],[StartDate]
having YEAR([StartDate]) > 2001
```

Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Could you provide some insert table and create table scripts

Comment: @SurajKumar But how does that help?Sorry just trying to understand

Comment: Take the EmpNo out of the grouping, and put it into a count(EmpNo)  for the NoOfEmployees

Comment: @SeanR But than on what column i should do grouping?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but here it is:

```
select EmpNO, max(DeptName), SUM(Salary) total_sal
from EmpContracts 
where year(StartDate) > 2001
group by EmpNo
having count(distinct DeptName) =1;
```

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=977645e57d69929557612e589079e671)

Comment: But in your output, you are getting emp no 1 which is not correct because emp no 1 is working in more than 1 department(see my sample data) and in my first condition it says “ employees that work exclusively for that department”.

Comment: Hi @ILoveStackoverflow here is a new solution. I did not understood that from your explanation which is why is always a great thing to have a expected results in your question. Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ILoveStackoverflow was this answer helpful to you ? It now does return what you have asked for. If it is helpful please up vote. Is it correct, I believe it is. Then also mark the answer as correct. If non of the above, please comment as oyu did first time to see what it is ?